# Cards that double mana

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building

I am looking for a card that doubles my mana.

I have found [Doubling Cube](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDoubling%20Cube%5d), but I'm not sure if it is good or not? If anyone know something better please let me know. I have a Blue Red Black Commander deck.

Answer (score 3):

There is only one card that doubles all kinds of mana, and that is Doubling Cube.

There are also some cards that generate mana when certain kinds of sources generate mana, which effectively doubles mana from those sources. [This Scryfall search](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3Awhen%20o%3A%22for%20mana%22%20o%3Aadd%20ci%3Aurb) shows several cards that do that in your colors (plus a couple of false positives). Some of those cards that are popular in Commander are

- [Crypt Ghast](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrypt%20Ghast%5d)
- [Extraplanar Lens](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bExtraplanar%20Lens%5d)
- [Gauntlet of Power](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGauntlet%20of%20Power%5d)

Another card with similar functionality is [Liliana of the Dark Realms](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLiliana%20of%20the%20Dark%20Realms%5d), a planeswalker with this ultimate ability:

> −6: You get an emblem with "Swamps you control have '{T}: Add {B}{B}{B}{B} to your mana pool.'"

Answer (score 0):

As you can probably see from the previous answer, With your colours there aren't many effective methods of doubling mana... However Rakdos (Red/Black) has good cards that can reduce costs or generate manna when certain criteria are met. The most worthy mentions I've ran into are:

[Rakdos, Lord of Riots](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRakdos%2c%20Lord%20of%20Riots%5d)

[Neheb, The Eternal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNeheb%2c%20The%20Eternal%5d)

[This search result](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?text=%20[Add]%20[mana]%20[pool]&color=%20@([U]%7C[B]%7C[R])) shows many Red, Blue and Black "Mana Dorks" for increasing mana.